# Existe alguma forma de diminuir o tamanho da chamada de uma função?

Tags: c#, método, estilo-de-codificação

Exemplo: `StringFormats.DateTimeToShortDateStrPtBR();`

Se adicionar esse método diversas vezes na mesma linha o código vai ser muito extenso, repetitivo e confuso.

O método é apenas um exemplo, mas em casos como esse onde se repete muito, existe alguma forma de encurtar essa chamada?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Até existe mas em geral não compensa. Você faz o que chamamos de abstração, portanto cria outro método que chama este e aí dá um nome menor (melhor). Em alguns casos pode até ter uma otimização e não ter custo adicional, mas pode não ter essa otimização por uma série de circunstâncias e aí você paga um preço de execução para digitar menos.

```
public static class DateUtils { //algumas pessoas criticam este tipo de coisa
    public static string ToShortDatePtBr() => StringFormats.DatetTimeToShortDateStrPtBR();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/StaticExample.cs).

Muda muito pouco porque chamará assim:

```
DateUtils.ToShortDatePtBr();
```

Em alguns contextos é possível aplicar alguma técnica diferente para obter algum resultado, mas nada que indique na pergunta.

E obviamente sendo um código seu no método original pode mudar a escrita dele para dar nomes mais curtos (não que eu esteja recomendando porque depende de contexto também, e não parece muito que este seja o caso a não ser talvez pelo `DatetTime` inicial e quem sabe esse `Str`, ou seja, o nome original é mal definido). O problema deste nome é que ele parece ter sido mal definido, não é que precise ficar menor, precisa ficar melhor. Se fosse fazer isso com um método com um bom nome certamente só pioraria por dar um nome menor.

Não acho extenso algo que seja legível para indicar o que o método está fazendo. Em geral encurtar mais do que deve tirando a legibilidade da significância do que está executando ali é pior, inclusive esse encurtamento pode facilmente aumentar a confusão por não indicar bem o que está fazendo.

E isso nada tem a ver com repetição. Se usar isto uma vez não tem repetição, se o método chamar `A` e usar 2 vezes terá repetição, portanto a pergunta parte de premissa errada.